# who found that translation in N space is the same as shearing in N+1 space?

Tags: math-history, affine-geometry

According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix),

> Although a translation is a non-linear transformation in a 2-D or 3-D
>   Euclidean space described by Cartesian coordinates, it becomes, in a
>   3-D or 4-D projective space described by homogeneous coordinates, a
>   simple linear transformation (a shear).

I think this is one of the coolest thing I have learned in geometry. Now, I'm wondering who was the first to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) were introduced by [August Ferdinand Möbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Ferdinand_Moebius) in his 1827 work *Der barycentrische Calcül*. However, the coordinates you're interested in, where a point $(x,y)$ is promoted to $(x,y,1)$, were introduced by [Julius Plücker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Pluecker) in 1831, in the second volume of his *Analytisch-geometrische Entwicklungen*.

Source: Kline, *Mathematical Thought From Ancient to Modern Times*, Volume 3, [page 853](http://books.google.com/books?id=Lvco6V8fBpoC&pg=PA853)